# n-th element of a recursive section with complex roots

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

How can I find nth element of a recursive sequence?

$$x_n=x_{n-5} - x_{n-10}$$
$$x_0=...=x_9=1$$

There are complex roots in the characteristic equation :(

Comment: Same way as when there are no complex roots.

Comment: Also you might start writing out the sequence and notice a pattern which can be exploited in the solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson can you show how, please?

Comment: Sorry, Sher, I assumed you knew what to do if all the roots were real. If you don't know that, maybe that's where you should start. There have been lots of questions posted here on recurrences, you could probably find out how to handle the real case from some earlier question.

Comment: Or, you could follow the advice from @Mark.

Comment: So, are you there yet, Sher?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've found my n-th element with pattern ;)

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up what you have found, and to post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial task was to find not n-th element but 2021st. Here's my solution
$$x_{2021} = x_{2016} - x_{2011} = x_{2011} - x_{2006} - x_{2011} = \underline{-x_{2006}} = -(x_{2011}-x_{1996})=-(x_{1996}-x_{1991}-x_{1996})=\underline{x_{1991}}=(x_{1986}-x_{1981})=(x_{1981} - x_{1976}-x_{1981}) = \underline{-x_{1976}} = \ldots$$
So the pattern tells us
$$x_{2021} = x_{2021-15n} * (-1)^n$$
Max $n$ such that $2021 - 15n > 0$ is $134$. So the answer is:
$$x_{11}*(-1)^{134} = (x_6-x_1) = 0$$

Note:
Here's the simple C code to check the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[2022];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array[i] = 1;
    for (int i = 10; i < 2022; i++)
        array[i] = array[i-5]-array[i-10];
    printf("%d\n", array[2021]);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Let us try with $a_n = \gamma^n$. After substitution we have $\gamma^n=\gamma^{n-5}-\gamma^{n-10}$ so the recurrence is satisfied if $\gamma^{10}=\gamma^5-1$ then making $\lambda= \gamma^5$ we have equivalently $\lambda^2=\lambda-1$ and then for $\lambda = \frac 12(1\pm i\sqrt{3}) = e^{\pm i\frac{\pi}{3}}$ etc.

NOTE

The recurrence is real so the complex solutions should combine as sinusoidal terms.